# How to stop/prevent maven default goal execution

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I have a parent pom which is serving required version number variables of my other components & more importantly "maven-jar-plugin"(version 3.0.2). That same pom is having default profile which will make its multi-module child build a jar. Now the problem is that Multi-module child is throwing this below exception

> You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the
>   project instead of replacing them

I found that this is because of maven-jar-plugin default binding inherent to the jar packaging but I am doing a war packaging so after war packaging the default-jar execution starts and throwing the above one. Any solution to stop the default will help me thanks in advance.

```
pom(Master pom)
  + pom(Multi-Module child)
     +-- pom (war child pom, but after the war, it starts building default jar) 
       +-- pom2
       +-- pom3
```

Comment: Please show the pom files ...cause it sounds like you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include in your war-pom

```
    <build>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ....
    </build>
```

Comment: In such case, we are not getting the variables inherited from the parent pom :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but do not undestand what you ean with 'we are not getting the variables'. You do not need any variables to skip the `maven-jar-plugin`